# How do I access variables in an array of type struct in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How do I access variables of a struct within array? I've tried isolating the variables by printing the array itself and by printing the array with the first index but there's no output.

```
taskList: [["vacuum", "20 mins", "medium"], ["take out trash", "5 mins", "low"]] // list to choose from

struct Task { //to reassign from multidimensional array
var name: String = "None"
var time: String = "None"
var materials: String = "None"
}

var newTask = Task() //creation of a new task
var taskPool = [Task]() //pool of selected tasks

newTask.name = taskList[0][0]//assign name found in another list
newTask.time = taskList[0][1]//assign time found in another list
newTask.materials = taskList[0][2]//assign priority found in another list
taskPool += [newTask]
println(taskPool)
println(taskPool[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can access it:

```
var taskList = [["vacuum", "20 mins", "medium"],["take out trash", "5 mins", "low"]] // list to choose from

struct Task { //to reassign from multidimensional array
    var name: String = "None"
    var time: String = "None"
    var materials: String = "None"
}

var newTask = Task() //creation of a new task
var taskPool = [Task]() //pool of selected tasks
//
newTask.name = taskList[0][0]//assign name found in another list
newTask.time = taskList[0][1]//assign time found in another list
newTask.materials = taskList[0][2]//assign priority found in another list
taskPool += [newTask]

taskPool              // [{name "vacuum", time "20 mins", materials "medium"}]
taskPool[0].name      // "vacuum"
taskPool[0].time      // "20 mins"
taskPool[0].materials // "medium"
```